# How to use aliases for calculation in Laravel raw query?

Tags: laravel, raw

I want to use aliases column for calculations, and then I want to apply the orderBy on that calculated value, below is the query in which I have two aliases products_total_cost and sales, what I want to do is making a new aliases by this formula,
((sales - products_total_cost ) / sales) as margin_value

```
  $products = Warehouse::select(DB::raw('SUM(CASE 
  WHEN o.primary_status="3" THEN (op.actual_cost * op.qty_shipped) 
  END) AS products_total_cost,
  CASE 
  WHEN o.primary_status="3" THEN SUM(op.total_price) END AS sales,CASE 
  WHEN o.primary_status="3" THEN SUM(op.vat_amount_total) END AS vat_amount_total,CASE 
  WHEN o.primary_status="3" THEN SUM(op.import_vat_amount) END AS import_vat_amount'),'warehouses.warehouse_title','warehouses.id as wid','op.user_warehouse_id','op.product_id','o.customer_id','o.dont_show')->groupBy('warehouses.id');
  $products->join('order_products AS op','op.user_warehouse_id','=','warehouses.id');
  $products->join('orders AS o','o.id','=','op.order_id');
  $products->where('o.dont_show', 0);
  $products = $products->where('o.primary_status',3);
  $products = $products->whereNotNull('op.product_id');
```

below I have a SQL query and I want to implement this in laravel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xe61.png)

Comment: It makes no sense to be using `SUM` here without `GROUP BY`.  You might want to also include the raw MySQL query in your question above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have added a screenshot